# Struts2 json and ajax integration is not working

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin

Here I am trying into integrating Struts 2 with JSON ,jQuery and ajax It is calling to the action class but i am not getting json response. I have added all json plugin and json-defult in struts-xml

**Ajax function**

```java
function callajax() {
    alert(1);
    $.getJSON('edituser.action', function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
```

**Action class.**

```java
package com.hyva.accounts.master.useraccountsetup;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

/**
 *
 * @author ranjeeth.g
 */
public class MasterUserSetUpActionEdit extends ActionSupport {

    private String username = "ranjith";
    private String password = "1234";
    private String fullname = "Ranjith";
    private String emailaddress = "Ranjith";
    private String telephone = "8762232246";

    @Override
    public String execute() {
//        System.out.println("session = " + session.isOpen());
        return "success";
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getEmailaddress() {
        return emailaddress;
    }

    public void setEmailaddress(String emailaddress) {
        this.emailaddress = emailaddress;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
}
```

Struts-xml

```java
<action name="edituser" class="com.hyva.accounts.master.useraccountsetup.MasterUserSetUpActionEdit">
            <result type="json"></result>
   </action>
```

Updated code;

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="accounts" namespace="/" extends="hibernate-default,json-default">    
        <action name="login" class="com.hyva.accounts.userlogin.LoginAction" >
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/login.jsp</result> 
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>          
        </action> 

        <action name="edituser" class="com.hyva.accounts.master.useraccountsetup.MasterUserSetUpActionEdit">
            <result type="json"></result>
        </action>

        <action name="userlist"  class="com.hyva.accounts.master.useraccountsetup.MasterUserSetUpActionList">
            <result name="success">/setup_useracount_list.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="adduser"  class="com.hyva.accounts.master.useraccountsetup.MasterUserSetUpAction">
            <interceptor-ref name="jsonValidationWorkflowStack"/>
            <result name="input">/setup_useracount_list.jsp</result> 
            <result name="success">/setup_useracount_list.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="countryList" method="list" class="com.hyva.accounts.master.country.CountryAction">
            <result name="success">/setup_country_list.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="addCountry" method="saveOrUpdate" class="com.hyva.accounts.country.CountryAction">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">countryList</result>
        </action>         
    </package>
</struts>
```

**If call to this url i am getting**

```java
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/xwork/StringUtils
    org.apache.struts2.json.SerializationParams.<init>(SerializationParams.java:57)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.writeToResponse(JSONResult.java:214)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:204)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:361)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:265)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
```

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: i call to this url i am getting http://localhost:8088/iAccountsWeb/edituser.action

Comment: Use same versions for S2 core and plugin jars.

Answer (score 1):

1) Include json according to your struts2 version from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-json-plugin)

2) Your package should extends `json-default` as below

```
<package name="example1" extends="struts-default, json-default">
<action name="edituser" class="com.hyva.accounts.master.useraccountsetup.MasterUserSetUpActionEdit">
            <result type="json"></result>
   </action>
</package>
```

3)Check your action for json result  like your action name in address bas     `http://localhost:8080/edituser`

It will show json response to browser.

Comment: thanks for your replay this is what i am using struts2-core-2.1.6.jar and struts2-json-plugin-2.1.8.1.jar and i have updated my code please look at above.

Answer (score 0):

Include Apache's `commons-lang-2.x.jar`.

Then, since major changes occurred in 2.1.8, be aware that mixing 2.1.6 with 2.1.8 stuff is **really, really bad**.

Use the same version for all your struts libraries. Struts-core, Struts-json, others if any (struts-spring-plugin, struts-config-browser-plugin, struts-junit-plugin, etc). All except struts-jquery-plugin, frremarker and ognl (that btw must be picked with respect to the right version as specified in [Struts dependecies page](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/dependency-management.html)).

Then it is fundamental trying to upgrade to the latest version (2.3.16.3), due to security issues (and other reasons). If you'll go that way, then include both Apache's `commons-lang-2.x.jar` and Apache's `commons-lang3-3.x.jar` (if only the latter isn't enough, because of legacy code). Since they're in different package, they can cohexist.